# Logstash : Get timestamp from mysql doesn't work, convert it to string it work?

Tags: mysql, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

I'm using this conf file to overwrite the @timestamp field in ElasticSearch, but I automatically get an `_dateparsefailure` flag:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:/path/to/mariadb-java-client.jar"
        statement => "SELECT '${FIELD}' as field, from ${TABLE_NAME}"
        tracking_column => "timestamp"
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp" 
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["timestamp","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
    }
}
```

> Note that with or without the grok filter I get the same result.

The result:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2022-12-13T09:16:10.365Z,
    "timestamp" => 2022-11-23T10:36:13.000Z,              
    "@version" => "1",
    "tags" => [
        [0] "_dateparsefailure"
    ],
    "type" => "mytype",
}
```

But when I extract the timestamp with this conf:

```
input {
    *same input*
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["timestamp","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tmp}"]
        tag_on_failure => [ "_grokparsefailure"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["tmp", "ISO8601"]
    }
}
```

then it give me the expected result:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2022-11-23T11:16:36.000Z,
    "@version" => "1",
    "timestamp" => 2022-11-23T11:16:36.000Z,
    "tmp" => "2022-11-23T11:16:36.000Z",
}
```

Can anyone explain me why is that and how can I avoid create this extra field ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
The first parse a string I guess, but `timestamp` already has the right type,
So a copy is enough to save and overwrite the `@timestamp` field:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        copy => { "@timestamp" => "insertion_timestamp" }
        copy => { "timestamp" => "@timestamp" }
        remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database column type is a timestamp then the jdbc input will automatically convert the field to a LogStash::Timestamp object, not a string. A date filter [cannot parse](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/issues/95) a Timestamp object, and will add a _dateparsefailure tag.

A grok filter [calls .to_s](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/blob/bf2182a65ee6bb4053448e92cb13bdcb70cd9081/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb#L366) to convert everything to a string before matching it, so if you grok the timestamp from the Timestamp object it will be a string that the date filter *can* parse.